# wiremock-groovy library syntax

Tags: groovy, spock, wiremock

I use library https://github.com/tomjankes/wiremock-groovy for WireMock in Spock tests.
My big concern is that Intellij Idea doesn't understand syntax and so do I.

Exmaple from documentation:

```
    wireMockStub.stub {
        request {
            method "GET"
            url "/some/thing"
        }
        response {
            status 200
            body "Some body"
            headers {
                "Content-Type" "text/plain"
            }
        }
    }
```

As far as I understand, `stub { ... }` is a method call with lambda as an argument. That's ok, going further.
`request {...}` is a method call with two arguments: `method` and `url`. Is it correct? Idea points to the static method of the class `WireMock`, but I'm in doubts, because pointed method has second arg named `urlPattern`, not just `url`.
Then we see something similar with `response`. Idea doesn't recognize it at all, so no hints, no syntax check and so on.

So, there are two main questions:
 - What is this syntax?
 - How to force idea to understand it?

Comment: From a first glance, this lib looks like it just sends those bodies as JSON over to the mocking server itself.  So with some DSLs you can annotate the closure args in groovy so that IDEA can do quite a good job with autocomplete etc.  Yet here you would have to write a GDSL file for idea to make that work it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> stub { ... } is a method call with lambda as an argument.

Correct, but the `{...}` is a Closure, not lambda.

> request {...} is a method call with two arguments: method and url. Is it correct?

No, both `method` and `url` are method calls. In Groovy parenthesis can be omitted for clarity, so for java developers the block can be rewritten as:

```
        request( {
            method( "GET" )
            url( "/some/thing" )
        } )
```

or

```
        request(){
          ...
        }
```

The whole thing is made possible by Groovy DSL support, which may not always be properly recognized be IDEs during compile time, but runs smoothly nevertheless.